# Adding curves to background in mobile view

Tags: html, css, reactjs, background, shapes

I am trying to recreate this background on mobile view, not sure if I should be creating the shapes or should I just use a background image and call it a day.

[image]

Appreciate any help or insight that I can get.

Here's my attempt to create 3 parts of shapes, right now the values are kinda hardcoded, so if a different device is used, the shape might not be consistent.

https://codepen.io/2EZHenry/pen/MWqaVXz

```
<div class="outerdiv"> 
  <div class="container">
    text
  </div>
</div>

.outerdiv {
  height:400px;
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center
}

.container{
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  background:blue;
  position:relative;
}

.container::before{
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  height: 180px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 100%;
  background: blue;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
}

.container::after{
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  height: 180px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  background:blue;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: use relative unit like `px,em,vw,vh` instead of px to make it responsive

Comment: Go to [Fancy Border Radius](https://9elements.github.io/fancy-border-radius/), select menu option 'full control' and have at it... For your 200:400 ratio I created `.container { border-radius: 0% 85% 0% 85% / 0% 40% 0% 40% }`, no `::before` or `::after`...

Answer (score 0):

Use relative units like Anil mentioned, then use media queries to target each specific device with modified css for that device.

@media only screen and (min-width: 275px) { ** css here ** }

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) { ** css here ** }